# How to write key events when the cursor inside the textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image]

Hi I am writing key events for remote for that screen, ups and downs working properly, the problem is when the cursor is inside the text field my key events is not working.

if anybody knows about key events plz help me.

Controller.js

```js
var unFocusText = function(){
         $("#search_all")[0].blur();
    };


case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.BACK:  
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.ESC:
  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.SELECT:

if (_isSearchItemHighlighted == 8) {                        
  $("#search_all")[0].focus();
}  

 break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.DOWN:
     if (searchScreen) {
     if (0 <= _isSearchItemHighlighted && _isSearchItemHighlighted <=            $scope.searchFilters.length-1) {
     isSearchItemHighlighted = 8;
                            
     }
     }

  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.RIGHT:
 if (_isSearchItemHighlighted == 8) {                        
  _isSearchItemHighlighted = 9;
  unFocusText();         
}

  break;
case PV.yoohu.appConstants.keyCodes.UP:

  if (_isSearchItemHighlighted == 8) {                        
    _isSearchItemHighlighted = 0;
    unFocusText();
  }
```

```html
<div id="searchCategory">
           <div id="searchFilter" ng-repeat="item in searchFilters"> 
                <input id="searchFilternames" type="radio"  ng-model="selectedFilter.name" 
                value="{{item.name}}" 
                ng-class="{'selected-search-asset-border': isSearchItemHighlighted($index)}" 
                ng-checked="isItemChecked(item, $index)"/><span
                ng-bind="item.name"></span>                
           </div>
        </div>   

        <input type="text" id="search_all" class="input" placeholder="enter text" ng-class="{'selected-search-asset-border': isSearchItemHighlighted(8)}"
        />&nbsp;

        <input type="image" id="searchButton"class="searchImage" src="resources/search1.png"
         ng-class="{'selected-search-asset-border': isSearchItemHighlighted(9)}" ng-click="availableSearchList()" />
```

index no of the search textfield is 8, if i press enter, when the Red Border in Search textfield the cursor will be focused, but after that my key events are not working.
Actually i wants to move controller to right and up from the text field.

What is the wrong in my code, Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is:

```
$("your_input").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
```

Another (worse) way is:

In case that your cursor is in the input and your key events arent working you should check every key which is pressed when the cursor is in the input. To do this you should add the change() function at your input and in the function you can check the keys that are pressed when the cursor is in the input

```
$( "your_input" ).change(function() {
      var key_pressed = your_input.text().slice(-1);
      if (key_pressed = "e" )
         //do that
    });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I edited my answer please check the first solution and tell me if it helped :)